# "upon" a future fact

Tags: word-usage

Is this a correct usage of **upon** ?

> Please update this document upon deprecation of the current policy.

Comment: **Yes**.  I have to type other things to get past the minimum character limit.

Comment: This is general reference: •upon ... [arguably] preposition
4. on the occasion of, at the time of, or immediately after: _She was joyful upon seeing her child take his first steps_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a correct usage, though I would prefer to use "on" instead.

> Please update this document on deprecation of the current policy.